# Drupal commerce Sql select max price for current taxonomy

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7, view

Hello (sorry for broken english). I try to select min and max prices (drupal commerce) for current catalog tag. ATM i put in header php code:

```
$max = db_query("SELECT MAX(`commerce_price_amount`) FROM {`field_data_commerce_price`}")->fetchField();
```

so I can get max price for all products. same for min.
but i need for current tag. my sql tables looks like this:

table field_data_field_product_catalog:
http://postimage.org/image/tahrk3y29/

table field_data_commerce_price:
http://postimage.org/image/w1yvkh8kn/

some advice plz?

Answer (score 1):

```
$catalog=arg(2);   
$max = db_query("SELECT MAX(`commerce_price_amount`) FROM {`field_data_field_product_catalog`},{`field_data_commerce_price`} 
WHERE {field_data_commerce_price.entity_id}={field_data_field_product_catalog.entity_id} 
AND {field_product_catalog_tid}=:cnid", array(':cnid' => $catalog))->fetchField();
$max=Ceil($max/100);
```